# Error in getting a desired ouput of Dropdown box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

what im trying to do to my code is to disable the 'Senior Highschool Track' dropdown button whenever i choose the "Junior Highschool" from the 'Education Level' dropdown button options

And when i choose the "Senior Highschool" from the 'Education Level' dropdown options it will enable the 'Senior Highschool Track' dropdown button and reset the value back to "SELECT TRACK",

"Education Level Dropdown HTML"

```
<td>
<select name="educlevel" class="StyleTextField" editable="true" edittext="" id="educlevel" onChange="disableDropdown()">
                            <option class="separator" disabled="disabled" selected>SELECT EDUCATION LEVEL</option>
                            <option value="JuniorHighschool" <?php echo  set_select('educlevel', 'Junior Highschool'); ?> >Junior Highschool</option>
                            <option value="SeniorHighschool" <?php echo  set_select('educlevel', 'Senior Highschool'); ?> >Senior Highschool</option>
                            <option value="College" <?php echo  set_select('educlevel', 'College'); ?> >College</option>
                            <option value="Graduate" <?php echo  set_select('educlevel', 'Graduate Program'); ?> >Graduate Program (Master)</option>
                        </select>
</td>
```

"Senior Highschool Track Dropdown HTML"

```
 <td><select name="seniorhstrack" class="StyleTextField" editable="true" edittext="" id="seniorhstrack" onChange="disableDropdown()">
                    <option class="separator" disabled="disabled" selected>SELECT TRACK</option>
                    <option id="seniorNA" value="NA" <?php echo  set_select('course', 'NA'); ?> >Not Applicable</option>
                    <option value="ABM" <?php echo  set_select('course', 'ABM'); ?> >Accountancy, Business and Management Strand</option>
                    <option value="HUMSS" <?php echo  set_select('course', 'HUMSS'); ?> >Humanities and Social Sciences Strand</option>
                    <option value="STEM" <?php echo  set_select('course', 'STEM'); ?> >Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics Strand</option>
                    <option value="TVL" <?php echo  set_select('course', 'TVL'); ?> >Technical Vocational Livelihood Strand</option>
                </select>
            </td>
```

"Javacript that I made"

```
function disableDropdown()
{
    if (document.getElementById("educlevel").value === "JuniorHighschool") {
        document.getElementById("course").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("seniorhstrack").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("seniorNA").selected=true;
        document.getElementById("courseNA").selected=true;
        document.getElementById("seniorNA").style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("educlevel").value === "SeniorHighschool") {
        document.getElementById("course").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("seniorhstrack").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("courseNA").selected=true;
        document.getElementById("seniorNA").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if ((document.getElementById("educlevel").value === "College") || (document.getElementById("educlevel").value === "Graduate")){
        document.getElementById("seniorhstrack").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("course").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("courseNA").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("seniorNA").selected=true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("course").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("seniorhstrack").disabled=false;
    }
}
```

I already tried putting this code

```
document.getElementById("seniorhstrack").selectedIndex = 0;
```

However, the issues that im getting is that it wont let me choose the other options, it just stays at the selected index which is "SELECT TRACK".

Im still learning javascript and any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Would you mind to replace this server side code by html from browser output? Thanks.

Comment: You need to give us the rest of the dropdowns as well as the case to repoduce the issue ie, select this value and then try to select that value to observe this issue

Comment: Is there a way where the dropdown button will reset its value and still be able to choose the other options in it?, document.getElementById("seniorhstrack").selectedIndex = 0;, this code resets the value but the problem is that, it wont let me choose the other options from the dropdown